# Returning nil when unable to locate value of true in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I need to be able to return nil when I can't find is_my_favorite? to have a value of true, and return the hash that is the favorite. My current code will return the hash that is true, but if they were all false for example, I want to return nil, but I can't come up with a way of doing so without breaking my code, which currently does half of what I want.

```
# array_of_hash_objects will look something like this:
  # [
  #   { name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true },
  #   { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false },
  #   { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }
  # ]
  array_of_hash_objects.each do |item|
    item.each do |words|
      if words.one?(true)
        return item
    
        
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried this:

```
  array_of_hash_objects.each do |item|
    item.each do |words|
      if words.one?(true)
        return item
      else
        return nil
    
        
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but this returns

Failure/Error: expect(find_favorite(array)).to eq(expected_output)

```
   expected: nil
        got: [{:is_my_favorite?=>false, :name=>"Python"}, {:is_my_favorite?=>false, :name=>"JavaScript"}, {:is_my_favorite?=>false, :name=>"HTML"}]
```

Comment: If all of them are false, the loop simply runs to its end, so you just put a `return nil` after the loop.  BTW, since `item` is a Hash, I don't see why you iterate over `item`. You could simply do a `return item if item[:is_my_favorite?]`, or even better use the approach in the answer given by _kkp_.

Comment: What if multiple hashes have a `:is_my_favorite?` value of `true`?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use the `find` method https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/find

```
array_of_hash_objects = [
  { name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true },
  { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false },
  { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }
]

array_of_hash_objects.find { |item| item[:is_my_favorite?] }
```

This will give you:

```
=> [{:name=>"Ruby", :is_my_favorite?=>true}]
```

Now if you got an array with all false values in the hash:

```
array_of_hash_objects = [
  { name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: false },
  { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false },
  { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }
]
array_of_hash_objects.find { |item| item[:is_my_favorite?] }
```

You will get:

```
=> nil
```